# Using parsed response in separate GET call

Tags: ruby, httparty

I'm new to Ruby and API, so my apologies if this is super simple...
I need to have script that will first POST to initiate the creation of an export file, and then have a GET call to retrieve the file.  The GET call needs to use part of the POST json response.

I'm using the httparty gem.

I think I need to create a variable that equals the parsed json, and then make that variable part of the GET call, but I'm not clear on how to do that.
Help is appreciated.

```
require 'httparty'
url = 'https://api.somewhere.org'
response = HTTParty.post(url)
puts response.parse_response
```

json response:

```
 export_files"=>
   {"id"=> #####,   
   "export_id"=> #####, 
   "status"=>"Queued"}}
```

In my GET call I need to use the export_id number in the url.

```
HTTParty.get('https://api.somewhere.org/export_id/####')
```

Comment: the parsed response will be a `Hash` so you can access the values in that fashion so in your case `HTTParty.get("https://api.somewhere.org/export_id/#{response.parse_response['export_files']['export_id']}")` should work. obviously this is simplified to fit in a comment without any form of error handling

Comment: Thanks! That worked well!

Answer (score 1):

As described in the comments but a bit more verbose and skeleton for error:

```
require 'httparty'
require 'json'

url = 'https://api.somewhere.org'
response = HTTParty.post(url)

if hash = JSON.parse(response.body)
  if export_id = hash[:export_files][:export_id]
    post = HTTParty.post("https://api.somewhere.org/export_id/#{export_id}")
  end
else
  # handle error 
end
```